# c++ macro recognizing tokens as arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c-preprocessor

So, it's been a while since I have written anything in C++ and now I'm working on a project using C++11 and macros.

I know that by using the stringify operator I can do this:

```
#define TEXT(a) #a    //expands to "a"
```

How am I supposed to use the preprocessor for recognizing the tokens like + and * to do this:

```
#define TEXT(a)+ ???  //want to expand to "a+"
#define TEXT(a)* ???  //want to expand to "a*"
```

when the input has to be in that syntax?

I have tried doing that:

```
#define + "+"
```

but of course it doesn't work. How can I make the preprocessor recognize those tokens?

**NOTE:**
This is actually part of a project for a small language that defines and uses regular expressions, where the resulting string of the macros is to be used in a *regex*. The syntax is given and we have to use it as it is without making any changes to it.

eg
`TEXT(a)+` is to be used to make the regular expression: `std::regex("a+")`
without changing the fact that `TEXT(a)` expands to "a"

Answer (score 2):

First,

```
#define TEXT(a) #a
```

doesn't “convert to `"a"`”. `a` is just a name for a parameter. The macro expands to a string that contains whatever `TEXT` was called with. So `TEXT(42 + rand())` will expand to `"42 + rand()"`. Note that, if you pass a macro as parameter, the macro will not be expanded. `TEXT(EXIT_SUCCESS)` will expand to `"EXIT_SUCCESS"`, not `"0"`. If you want full expansion, add an additional layer of indirection and pass the argument to `TEXT` to another macro `TEXT_R` that does the stringification.

```
#define TEXT_R(STUFF)   # STUFF
#define TEXT(STUFF)     TEXT_R(STUFF)
```

Second, I'm not quite sure what you mean with `TEXT(a)+` and `TEXT(a)*`. Do you want, say, `TEXT(foo)` to expand to `"foo+"`? I think the simplest solution in this case would be to use the implicit string literal concatenation.

```
#define TEXT_PLUS(STUFF)  # STUFF "+"
#define TEXT_STAR(STUFF)  # STUFF "*"
```

Or, if you want full expansion.

```
#define TEXT_R(STUFF)     # STUFF
#define TEXT_PLUS(STUFF)  TEXT_R(STUFF+)
#define TEXT_STAR(STUFF)  TEXT_R(STUFF*)
```

Comment: First, thanks for making more clear to me. I have corrected my "convert" mistake.
Second, yeah that's exactly what I want to do but I can't change the syntax of TEXT(a)+. It has to be written in that exact way in the code and to be expanded to "a+"

Comment: I don't believe that this is possible. What *is* possible, tough, is to use a bag of template-meta-programming and use operator overloading. The downside is that you have to write `+TEXT(a)` and `*TEXT(a)`. But I think that this is the closest you will be able to get.

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment is impossible to solve in C++. You either misunderstood something or there’s an error in the project specification. At any rate, we’ve got a problem here:

> `TEXT(a)+` is to be used to make the regular expression: `std::regex("a+")` *without changing the fact that `TEXT(a)` expands to `"a"`* [my emphasis]

`TEXT(a)` expands to `"a"` — meaning, we can just replace `TEXT(a)` everywhere in your example; after all, that’s exactly what the preprocessor does. In other words, you want the compiler to transform this C++ code

```
"a"+
```

into

```
std::regex("a+")
```

And that’s simply impossible, because the C++ preprocess does not allow expanding the `+` token.

The best we can do in C++ is use operator overloading to generate the desired code. However, there are two obstacles:

- You can only overload operators on custom types, and `"a"` isn’t a custom type; its type is `char const[2]` (why 2? Null termination!).
- Postfix-`+` is not a valid C++ operator and cannot be overloaded.

If your assignment had just been *a little* different, it would work. In fact, if your assignment had said that `TEXT(a)++` should produce the desired result, and that you are allowed to change the definition of `TEXT` to output something other than `"a"`, then we’d be in business:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

#define TEXT(a) my_regex_token(#a)

struct my_regex_token {
    std::string value;

    my_regex_token(std::string value) : value{value} {}

    // Implicit conversion to `std::regex` — to be handled with care.

    operator std::regex() const {
        return std::regex{value};
    }

    // Operators

    my_regex_token operator ++(int) const {
        return my_regex_token{value + "+"};
    }

    // more operators …
};

int main() {
    std::regex x = TEXT(a)++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to jab characters onto the end of macros.

Maybe you simply want something like this:

```
#define TEXT(a, b) #a #b
```

that way `TEXT(a, +)` gets expanded to "a" "+" and `TEXT(a, *)` to "a" "*"

If you need that exact syntax, then use a helper macro, like:

```
#define TEXT(a) #a
#define ADDTEXT(x, y) TEXT(x ## y)
```

that way, `ADDTEXT(a, +)` gets expanded to "a+" and `ADDTEXT(a, *)` gets expanded to "a*"

Comment: Well, yeah I thought about this solution too but the input has to be in that exact syntax...

Comment: @NenaB You’re saying “has to be in that exact syntax” but what you’ve posted is simply not legal C++. How do you want to use the macro?

Comment: The `##` operator has to be used to combine two identifiers or partial identifiers; you can't use it to paste an identifier and an operator symbol.  The `ADDTEXT(x, y)` won't work properly when `y` is `*` or `+`, for example.  Whether your compiler actually complains probably depends on the warning level you have set — but officially, it won't work.  _If the result [of concatenating the two tokens] is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined._  That means it may work, but equally it may not.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Read the added Note

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too:

```
#define TEXT(a) "+"  // "a" "+" -> "a+"
#define TEXT(a) "*"  // "a" "*" -> "a*"
```

Two string literals in C/C++ will be joined into single literal by specification.

Comment: You can't redefine a macro with a different replacement sequence without an intervening `#undef`, and you can't have two identically named macros doing different jobs at the same time.  The question isn't clear about this either, it would seem — so this is a carryover from the question.